# php youtube api comments list jQuery data on scroll

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-data-api

i'm printing youtube video comments but upload data as scrollbar goes down. I have no jquery information that can help.

I applied to you because I couldn't solve the pagination logic.

Please be happy if you are the subject before doing points. please do not dislike before reading the subject.
I can achieve something new, please don't judge

```
function get_CURL($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}

function get_Comment($limit)
{
    $url = "CRZ7KtbtQk8";
    $nextPage = "";
    $ytkey = "...";
    $com = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=" . "$ytkey" . "&textFormat=plainText&order=relevance&part=snippet&videoId=" . "$url" . "&maxResults=" . "$limit"
        . "&nextPageToken=" . "$nextPage";
    return get_CURL($com);
}
if (isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])) {
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $nextPage = get_Comment($limit, "")['nextPageToken'];
        foreach (get_Comment($limit)['items'] as $val) {
            $author = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName'];
            $author_thumbnail_url = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorProfileImageUrl'];
            $comment = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'];

            echo "<img src='$author_thumbnail_url'> <span style='color:red';>" . "$author" . "</span>" . " --> " . "$comment";
            echo "<hr>";
        }
    }
}
```

```
<div id="post"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var flag = 0;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "vlog-detail",
            data: {
                'offset': 0,
                'limit': 1
            },
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('post').innerHTML = data;
                flag += 1;
            }
        });

        window.onscroll = function () {
            myFunction()
        }
        function myFunction() {
            var flag = 0;
            if (document.getElementById('post').scrollTop > 350 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "vlog-detail",
                    data: {
                        'offset': flag,
                        'limit': 1
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        document.getElementById('post').innerHTML = data;
                        flag += 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It is really not clear what your problem is and what question you are actually asaking. If you dont want to be downvoted, you have to ask an understandable question. If English is not you first Language, then use a translator like Google Translate. Ask the question in your own language and then paste the English translation in the question

Comment: I want to upload comments with the help of Scroolbar. As in Youtube comments.I hope I could express myself